# Suspension of Connected Space Simply Connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a ***connected*** and ***well pointed*** topological space (the latter means that $\{*\} \hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration).

Is then $X$ already ***path connected***? If yes why?

Background: Under the same conditions for $X$ as above I want to show that the reduced suspesion $\Sigma X$ is simple connected.

Using decompsion by cones $\Sigma X = C_+X \cup C_-X$ I intend to apply Seifert-van-Kampen. But here I need the path connectness of $X \cong C_+X \cap C_-X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to your first question is "no."  (You may have to assume path-connectedness for $X$ in order to get that $\Sigma X$ is simply-connected.  I've never seen an argument for this that avoided making that assumption.)

Take as $X$ the topologist's sine curve with a basepoint $x_0$.  If this is well-pointed, you already have your counterexample.  If not, apply the "whisker trick" to $X$, where we attach an interval $[0,1]$ at $x_0$ and move the basepoint down to the dangling end of the interval.  This resulting space is well-pointed, still connected, homotopy equivalent to $X$, but still not path-connected.  This whiskered sine curve would then be a counterexample.

Comment: But is the condition that $X$ path connected ***neccessary*** or only sufficent? Is there nevertheless a way to show that $\Sigma X$ is simply connected using the above conditions for $X$ despite it's not path connected?

Comment: Well, that's a different question and I do not know the answer.